# What is the practical difference between a sub-workflow and the includes directive? [Snakemake]

Tags: workflow, snakemake

In the Snakemake documentation, the [`includes` directive](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/modularization.html#includes) can incorporate all of the rules of another workflow into the main workflow and apparently can show up in `snakemake --dag -n | dot -Tsvg > dag.svg`. [Sub-workflows](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/modularization.html#sub-workflows), on the other hand, can be executed prior to the main workflow should you develop rules which depend on their output.

My question is: how are these two really different? Right now, I am working on a workflow, and it seems like I can get by on just using `includes` and putting the name of the output in `rule all` of the main workflow. I could probably even place the output in the `input` of a main-workflow rule, making the `includes` workflow execute prior to that rule. Additionally, I can't visualize a DAG which includes the sub-workflow, for whatever reason. What do sub-workflows offer that the `includes` directive can't do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `include` doesn't "incorporate another workflow". It just adds the rules from another file, like if you add them with copy/paste (with a minor difference that `include` doesn't affect your target rule). The `subworkflow` has an isolated set of rules that work together to produce the final target file of this subworkflow. So it is well structured and isolated from both main workflow and other subworkflows.

Anyway, my personal experience shows that there are some bugs in Snakemake that make using subworkflows quite difficult. Including the file is pretty straightforward and easy.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used subworkflows, but here's a case where it may be more convenient to use them rather than the `include` directives. (In theory, I think you don't need `include` and `subworkflow` as you could write everything in a massive Snakefile, the point is more about convenience.)

Imagine you are writing a workflow that depends on result files from a published work (or from a previous project of yours). The authors did not make public the files you need but they provide a snakemake workflow to produce them. Their snakemake workflow may be quite complex and the files you need may be just intermediate steps. So instead of making sense of the all workflow and parsing it into your own `include` directives, you use `subworkflow` to generate the required file(s). E.g.:

```
subworkflow jones_etal:
    workdir:
        "./jones_etal"
    snakefile:
        "./jones_etal/Snakefile"

rule all:
    input:
        'my_results.txt',

rule one:
    input:
        jones_etal('from_jones.txt'),
    output:
        'my_results.txt',
    ...
```